# Need to understand how programming is done for cashback kind of websites

Tags: asp.net, payment

I have to develop a website which should give user some cashback based on his purchase on some referred website. For example, my site is cashbacktest.com and it will give users cash back coupon options for other websites say wallmart.com.

Now I do not understand how to code for this. I am using ASP.NET and have the following queries:
1. How will I get to know whether the user has actually made a purchase on the referred website.
2. As there could be many sites where I will refer from my cashbacktest.com, how will I code/progam to get a response  for purchase from the referred website.
3. Don't know if I have to work with each referred website to ask them to send me back some response code after successful purchase.

Some of the examples of referral or cashback based websites are ebates.com, deals2buy.com and many more.

Any advise on how to proceed would be appreciated.

Comment: This question is far too general to be answered here.

Comment: let me know what other details you need to make this specific? I did not find any other way or forum to ask this question.

Comment: Many cashback sites operate by virtue of affiliate marketing. Have a look at [Zanox](http://www.zanox.com), [Affilinet](http://www.affili.net), [Tradedoubler](http://www.tradedoubler.com/index.html), etc. The cashback site often registers as ad publisher with one or more of the networks, even if they often do not show the ads. The shops don't mind, as the cashback sites provide targeted, well-shaped traffic.

Comment: I researched more on ebates and found that it uses a "middle man" or "commission agent". and that commission agent does the work of handling session and coupon codes for purchases. So now I understand that I need to use some commission agent and just focus on my first level of site to display cashback features.

Comment: @Pawan Hi, were you able to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

If you provide coupons after they've made purchases on other sites, then you need to:

1. Ask a user to enter a, for example, receipt number, to confirm their purchase.
2. Have a web service set up at the store's site that you can query and ask if the receipt is indeed from their database, and if it's eligible for cash back - get an amount based on their policy.

An automation has to occur on both sides - your site and stores database/web service, designed for this cash back functionality.

Keep in mind that if you need a store to be able to register a purchase at their side and then credit you the cashback, they all need a software adjustment at their side to handle an accounting and other stuff for that.

Comment: Thanks Maxim for the answer. I think the receipt logic is fine. But for the second point you mentioned, I think there should be some other way. Like there are corporate perks sites and other cashback sites which just provide you with cashback or some discount like 15% when store site is opened via them. Dont know how to achieve this.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "when the store is opened via them"? If you clear out the logical part of me understanding what you are trying to achieve, I might be able to alter the answer.

Comment: Say I give a link of wallmart.com and display that user will get $5 cashback on any purchase greater than $25. So, "when the store is opened via them" means when user clicks the wallmart.com link from my site and go to it. So, I want to understand how I can provide this $5 cashback to the user. How to know whether user has actually made a purchase or not. Does it always have to be like, I have to provide a coupon code and user has to enter this code in the store site. Is it not possible that I can just maintain this $5 information at my end and user can collect cashback from many purchases....

Comment: Do you need to cover only online purchases?

Comment: .. continuing on above comment... user can collect cashback form may purchases and then later use all the collected amount for some purchase, or I give the user a cashback check. Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: Answering to covering only online purchases.. No I want to handle both online and offline purchases. But I think offline purchase could be handled by gicing a coupon code when user can take print out and take to the seller. But currently I want to develop a website which can provide cashback feature for online purchases with both coupon code and cashback features. thanks.

Comment: @Pawan, as for ebates.com model - they have the system at store's side that allows the store to record, which purchase was lead to them from you. You develop and most likely provide that system for them. Then you allow users to print a coupon at your site and ask them to register it at cashier in the store, but keep it to claim the cashback, when it is credited to you.

Comment: thansk a lot.. this clarify a lot of doubts. can you suggest any good books or online resources for get started with coding for financial websites.

Comment: I researched more on ebates and found that it uses a "middle man" or "commission agent". and that commission agent does the work of handling session and coupon codes for purchases. So now I understand that I need to use some commission agent and just focus on my first level of site to display cashback features.

Comment: If you are fine with reducing your profit in that manner - sure. But middle man is the same thing as you would just develop your own software to deploy at store's site.